# How to post input data variables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submit").click(function() {

    var emailVal = $(".email").val()

    $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
             url: 'settings/update',
             data: { email: emailVal },
             beforeSend:function(){

                //loading image
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');

             },
             success:function(data){

                 // successful request; do something with the data
                 $('#ajax-panel').empty();

                 $('#ajax-panel').html(data);     

             },
             error:function(){

                 // failed request; give feedback to user
                 $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
             }
          });
        });
      });
```

The emailVal variable is not getting sent as post data.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Does your URL `url: 'settings/update',` go to an actual file?

Comment: @Biotox... why would it have to go to a file?  what if he is using an MVC pattern with URIs.

Comment: Yes it does, I'm using firebug to debug... it keeps saying success but it's storing it as the string emailVal (regardless of whats in the textbox) ... but when I change the parameter to emailVal2 it says undefined variable

Comment: Can we see the HTML for your textbox ? Also why are you referencing it by class and not ID ?

Comment: OMFG, I'm such a fool.  Thanks Interstellar_Coder.  Been coding all day, overlooked such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a semi-colon at the end of this line.

```
var emailVal = $(".email").val()
```